# Application Loader: "Cannot proceed with delivery: an existing transporter instance is currently uploading this package"

Tags: itunes, app-store-connect

I have been unable to overcome this error in Application Loader.  I've quit, restarted, tried different computers - it's like the server is hung up on an op that I never initiated and it won't time out.  Has anyone seen it before and beaten it?

Answer (score 233):

Basically, you need to clear out the transport tokens. This can happen if you were to close out of Xcode while in the middle of submitting an app to iTunes Connect.

The token files now appear in the

> `Library/Caches/com.apple.amp.itmstransporter/UploadTokens/` subfolder of the given user's home directory. Which, honestly, is a better place for them anyway.

Delete any `.token` files in this directory.

--
If you are unable to find the **.token** files, this is because they are hidden in Finder. To hide/show hidden files in Finder, use the following Terminal command *(TRUE = UNHIDE, FALSE = HIDE)*:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE;killall Finder
```

Comment: from where i can find the .token or /Users/<username>/.itmstransporter/UploadTokens/

Comment: Seems like a good answer but I don't get the "basically" part. I have no idea on how to do this and I can't find these tokens anywhere. A good basic guide of how would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Open a console and type "rm ~/.itmstransporter/UploadTokens/*.token" (It happen to me beacause I have uploaded twice the same version of an application and Apple has rejected the second upload).

Comment: I tried this and found no tokens in the folder, however after an hour or so my build was successfully uploaded on itunesConnect. This may be due to a build already created and being processed on the website as it does not allow multiple builds to be uploaded at once. Weird!!

Comment: If you get this error, ideally you should look for these files, and check them with `fuser` to see if they are open files, or stale tokens. If one of them is an upload for  a currently running upload, force re-uploading is just going to cause a conflict bc both versions will have the same combination of version & build number.

Comment: my tokens are located in ```/Users/<#username#>/Library/Caches/com.apple.amp.itmstransporter/UploadTokens/```

Comment: To display all Files on MacOS without need for a terminal, you can also just use the keyboard shortcut `Cmd` + `Shift` + `.` in Finder (source: https://ianlunn.co.uk/articles/quickly-showhide-hidden-files-mac-os-x-mavericks/)

Comment: Worked for me. The Apple Notarization process is a horrendous drain on productivity. I get that they want to protect the user. The error messages are cryptic and uninformative.

Answer (score 74):

You need to clear out the transport tokens.

Open Terminal on your Mac, and paste:

```
rm /Users/<username>/Library/Caches/com.apple.amp.itmstransporter/UploadTokens/*.token
```

That should clear the stuck token. After this, try uploading the build again.

Comment: Of all the answers I read, this was the only one that solved it for me. Thanks!

Comment: If you ran into this on your own machine (not CICD setup or something...): 'rm ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.amp.itmstransporter/UploadTokens/*.token'

Comment: this is helpful especially with fastlane

Answer (score 42):

It might be because Xcode crashed as you were uploading your app. Either, all you need to do is delete the token files:

Open Terminal on your Mac, and paste:

```
rm ~/.itmstransporter/UploadTokens/*.token
```

That should clear it. If it still doesn't work (at this point you should try re-uploading your app), run that command on Terminal again, or manually go to...

```
/Users/<username>/.itmstransporter/UploadTokens/
```

...and delete all the .token files.

Hope that helps!

Comment: easiest answer on the page

Comment: Helped me. You save my day :)

Answer (score 5):

token was in here

/Users/(user_name)/Library/Caches/com.apple.amp.itmstransporter/UploadTokens/

Answer (score 2):

**Appreciated @WrightsCS 's answer** It helps me to overcome Application Loader issue.

I would like to highlight one more thing here.

I proceed as per @WrightsCS answer and it resolved Application loader error:

> Can not proceed with delivery: an existing transporter instance is currently uploading this package

But I found one more issue after removing all tokens from

> /Users//.itmstransporter/UploadTokens/

I went to [iTunesConnect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/) and clicked on **"My Apps"**, what I saw a message that "**Can not connect... please contact Apple**".

Here I don't know why it suddenly stops working!

I submitted the same build which was there on [iTunesConnect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/) for submission but it has shown as processing.

After submission of that build, [iTunesConnect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/) works fine! Also, I am able to see last uploaded build in a list for submission.

Answer (score 2):

In my case (I am using OSX Catalina), I was not able to find the folder:

```
Library/Caches/com.apple.amp.itmstransporter/UploadTokens/
```

Under my user home directory (even when showing hidden files and folders)

but it seems my problem was a bit different and I just closed xCode completely (every xCode window opened) and reopened it again then I archived my project and uploaded it without any issues

maybe this could help someone else fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear out the upload tokens that are "stuck". To do this, open the tokens file found in /users//.itmstransporter/UploadTokens/. You should see one line of text at the top that refers to your current upload token. Simply delete this line and save the file. You should now be able to submit your app again.

Cheers