# App failing validation: Unable to create Configuration directory: /user/username/.itmstransporter

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I recently switched to a different computer for my programming. it was another collegue's computer and was not reformated. i installed xCode on it. This is the first time i've tried to update an app of ours on this machine. i archived w/out errors and i validated w/out errors. when i go to submit, i get these two errors:

---

*Unable to create configuration directory: /Users/username/.itmstransporter

*Your home folder must be writable in order to save run-time configuration data. Please
ensure your home folder exists and is writable.

---

i am not a mac OS person and can barely get around on a mac. a coworker checked and i do have read/write permisions for /Users directory.

can i fix this or do i need to re-install xCode or the OS?

Comment: similar question w/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870082/application-loader-cannot-proceed-with-delivery-an-existing-transporter-insta/5334320#5334320

Comment: while similar, not quite the answer. that one is talking about if the .itmstransporter becomes corrupt and needing to remove it. my issue was i just wasn't able to create it (didn't have writing permission for /Users folder). thank you though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I belive this is because your username on that machine can not write to your home directory (some how)..

Try opening a finder window and "get info" on your home folder.  (from finder, Cmd-N opens a window, right click on the folder in the left that is your user name, that is your home folder, and select get info.  Right click might not work, if it does not work, use ctrl-click.)

In the "get info" dialog, at the bottom you will see "Sharing & Permissions" you may have to turn the triangle by clicking on it.  In the list, make sure your username has Read & Write prifileges, if not, you need to add them by logging in as an admin and changing them.

[image]

This photo is just for reference, but you can see justin (me) has Read & Write, that is what you need on your home directory.

Comment: i love you man! thank you so much for the help! this was it; my account is admin and it had read/write on the hard drive, but the /Users/username did not have an admin user. i added "Admins" and gave read/write and it uploaded! spent half a damn day on this. thank you again!