# `xcrun altool --upload-app` not responding on the first attempt and throws error on following attempts

Tags: xcode, app-store, app-store-connect, expo, ipa

I'm trying to submit expo react-native app to App Store for the first time.

It used to throw `Invalid Code Signing Entitlements` error, but I think, I've fixed it.

Now it's not responding when I do this for the first time after restarting my mac:

```
xcrun altool --upload-app -f ~/Downloads/my_generated_package.ipa -u my_apple_id@gmail.com
```

I've tried to wait for as long as an hour.

And all subsequent attempts to do this, result into this error:

```
Cannot proceed with delivery: an existing transporter instance is currently uploading this package”
```

I've tried to use recommendations from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870082/application-loader-cannot-proceed-with-delivery-an-existing-transporter-insta).
But there are no `.token` files in my `~/.itmstransporter/UploadTokens/`.

Also, there is nothing about my build being uploaded in appstoreconnect activity.