# My app won't upload because of the Transporter. How can I get round this?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, upload

I'm trying to upload my app to the app store and have tried a few time but with errors. I had fixed all the errors and then went to upload, however, I am now getting this error:

> Cannot proceed with delivery: an existing transporter instance is currently uploading this package

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of all that I tried, only this command helped me

```
rm /Users/<username>/Library/Caches/com.apple.amp.itmstransporter/UploadTokens/*.token
```

Replace `<username>` with your

Answer (score 2):

You need to clear out the transport tokens. On terminal run this command

rm ~/.itmstransporter/UploadTokens/*.token

and Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870082/application-loader-cannot-proceed-with-delivery-an-existing-transporter-insta) and this [link](https://code-examples.net/en/q/3b0d82) for complete solution.